# Add 3d animation before html load

Tags: css, html, 3d

I need to add 3D gate opening animation before page load but not as preloader because I don't want to break animation. I want to go full animation and then go to page like if possible to open the gate and as opening to see content of page

I just need hint advice or smth because I couldn't find it on internet or I was searching with wrong words

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking here, but I do have a solution to what I think is your question:

When making animations in html5, it is best to use Hype 3, which has a free trial you can download. When editing in Hype, you can adjust the start time of the html animation. Hype is the best html animator out there, it supports all formats and rotations. You can press the "Preview" button to see how the animation looks on your local browser, and you can adjust the timing accordingly. When you see the start time you want, you can upload your animation files to 000webhost or hostgator and then embed the animation into your site. If the site takes longer to load, and the animation seems to be finished when it becomes visible, you can adjust the start time of your animation in hype and re-export the files.

Comment: imagine you type www.example.com in browser and hit enter after that you want to see gate opening like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suw_5M24M1E on your screen and behind them content of website, so when gates are full open they fade (disapear) or some transition...

Comment: @Hotshot What you should do then is build your entire website in hype. That way your animation will be overlaid on your page, and you will see your site in the background. As far a transition, you can fade them to 0 opacity when you are done with the animation.

Comment: I'm using windows any alternative?

Comment: @Hotshot just install OSX Mavericks 9.01 on windows. There are plenty of tutorials on hoe to do It. If it still doesn't work you can write the html code for your animation by hand or ask a friend with a mac.